# AngularJS: How to use $http.post to enter value and receive data from API url

Tags: angularjs, api, url

I'm working on the project at school. They asked me to use $http.post to enter 2 value Day and Customer and show the json data in table. Could you help me with this, I've researched on how to use $http.post and fix the code but it won't work. Please show me what am I misunderstand or there is any way else to complete this. Thank you very much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> $http.post </title>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"> 
</script>

  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid grey;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    table tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }

    table tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-app="postapp" ng-controller="postservice">
    <div>
      Day : <input ng-model="day"><br /><br />
      Customer : <input ng-model="customer"><br /><br />
      <input type="button" value="Send" ng-click="postdata(day, customer)"> 
<br /><br />
    </div>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Environment</th>
        <th>Host</th>
        <th>IP</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>{{ x.ID}}</td>
        <td>{{ x.Status}}</td>
        <td>{{ x.Environment}}</td>
        <td>{{ x.Host}}</td>
        <td>{{ x.IP}}</td>
        <td>{{ x.Description}}</td>
        <td>{{ x.Time}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('postapp', []);

    app.controller('postservice', function postservice($scope, $http) {
      $scope.day = null;
      $scope.customer = null;

      $scope.postdata = function(day, customer) {
        var data = {
          day: day,
          customer: customer
        };

        $http.post("https://b0gtju7vp5.execute-api.us-east- 
1.amazonaws.com/staging", JSON.stringify(data))
          .success(function(response) {
            $scope.names = response;
          });
      };
    });
  </script>

</body>
```

Here is view what I have to do, hope this will make it more clearly.[View pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHZBK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jazzed it up a bit and added a loading spinner for you.

Also with the request being cross origin i.e making a request to a different url than the site it runs on you will need to run Chrome with CORS disabled. Chrome blocks these requests by default and you have to switch it of for development.

In the run box in windows paste in the following:

`chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome-dev-session" --disable-web-security`

If you have a mac google 'How to run Chrome with CORS disabled'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> $http.post </title>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <style>
        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid grey;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        table tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }

        table tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="postapp" ng-controller="postservice">
        <!-- Loading spinner that will be shown when requst is in progres -->
        <div ng-if="isLoading">
            loading data...
        </div>
        <!-- Hide the page content when loading data -->
        <div ng-if="!isLoading">
            <div>
                Day :
                <input ng-model="day">
                <br />
                <br /> Customer :
                <input ng-model="customer">
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="button" value="Send" ng-click="getNames(day, customer)">
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Environment</th>
                    <th>Host</th>
                    <th>IP</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
                    <td>{{ name.ID}}</td>
                    <td>{{ name.Status}}</td>
                    <td>{{ name.Environment}}</td>
                    <td>{{ name.Host}}</td>
                    <td>{{ name.IP}}</td>
                    <td>{{ name.Description}}</td>
                    <td>{{ name.Time}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <pre>{{names | json}}</pre>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('postapp', []);

        app.controller('postservice', function postservice($scope, $http) {
            $scope.day = null;
            $scope.customer = null;
            $scope.names = [];
            $scope.isLoading = false;

            $scope.getNames = function (day, customer) {
                $scope.isLoading = true;
                var data = {
                    day: day,
                    customer: customer
                };
                var url = "https://b0gtju7vp5.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staging";

                $http.post(url, data)
                    .then(
                        function (response) {
                            $scope.names = response;
                            $scope.isLoading = false;
                        },
                        function (error) {
                            alert('Failed to post data');
                            $scope.isLoading = false;
                        });
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, i'm very appreciate it. Can i asked why after i fill in the data for day and customer, the button Send won't run?

Comment: Whoops, forgot to rename the ng-click directive on the input to use the new method name in the controller. Have updated the answer. Previously it was using the postData method, but I had renamed it to getNames. For naming conventions its good to name methods to what they are actually doing as it might get confusing if you have multiple different posts.

Comment: I set up a dev server to run your code and its working now, edited the answer to explain how to run it in chrome with cors disabled as it was blocking cross origin requests when the getNames method was called. Also made some tweaks to code in the answer.

Comment: thank you very much for your help and explanation, it's work for me now, i will update CORS for the URL.

Comment: Hi there again, can I ask you for help once more. I have change the $http.post into $scope.names = response.data but it doesn't appear on the table above, can you explain this for me please, thank you.